# Differentiate service provider for bixby capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Does the user need to prefix his/her request with the service providers name and then use their specific command set? If no, how does Bixby solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some more context to your question as it would help us to understand it better? 

Some information regarding the nature of the request, description of the command set, overall use case the capsule is meant to address would help quite a bit.

Comment: for example, both "Expedia" and "Skyscanner" developed capsule for flight booking. They both have "book a flight from LA to SF" training in their capsule. So when user said "book a flight from LA to SF", which capsule should Bixby trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bixby Marketplace will allow end users to view available capsules and select certain capsules as their preferred choices. When an utterance is used that may hit multiple capsules, the user's preferred capsule is selected and used.

Details regarding the handling of real-time capsule conflicts will be made available when Marketplace launches.

Comment: This is very helpful. But I also have two questions regarding your comment. 1) what would happen in case the user didn't select any preferred capsule in the marketplace but his/her utterance does hit multiple capsules?  2) If the user selects a prerferred capsule (e.g. Expedia), does bixby also allow users to use alternative capsule for the same utterance by saying the capsule name? e.g. book a flight via skyscanner?

Comment: These are great questions and ones that will be answered in greater detail when Marketplace launches. Rest assured that there are solutions for both the use cases you've outlined.